# Не работает JS в WebView. Andorid 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, webview

В `WebView` отправляю код, который работает на 4.3. на 4.4 и выше не работает.

Следуя этому совету

> "Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher."

@JavascriptInterface добавил для тех методов которые выполняют какие либо манипуляции.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") Для onCreate
@SuppressLint("AddJavascriptInterface") для метода инициализации WebView
```

Вот метод который запускает в вебе нужную мне страницу

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void showPage(final String page) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @JavascriptInterface
            @Override
            public void run() {
                remove(chatFragment);
                contentWebView.loadUrl(PATH_TO_PAGE + page);
            }
        });


private static final String PATH_TO_PAGE = "javascript:window.location.hash=";
```

Типичная переменная `page = "'#/main/messages'";`

на 4.4 вижу белый фон и текст в верхней части страницы

#/main/messages

p.s.
      minSDK = 14.

targetSDK = 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена:

```
if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)) {
                    contentWebView.loadUrl(PATH_TO_PAGE + page);
                } else {
                    contentWebView.evaluateJavascript(PATH_TO_PAGE + page, null);
                }
```

Comment: Можете отметить это как правильный ответ галочкой.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev завтра можно будет